# How to dismiss uib-tooltip-html on iPad

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a tooltip on an HTML page implemented using AngularJS uib-tooltip-html:

```
<div>
    <i uib-tooltip-html="myTooltip='my tooltip HTML'"
       class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
</div>
```

It shows well on desktop browsers when I hover the icon with the mouse and disappears when the mouse is out of the icon area.

When I activate the tooltip on iPad, it doesn't disappear if I tap in other screen areas.

How to dismiss the uib-tooltip-html tooltip on iPad?

Comment: See this similar discussion on the github repository of angular-ui bootstrap: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2525

Comment: Thanks, will try that!

Comment: That thread is not for my question though.
I don't want to disable tooltips but have ability to dismiss them after they show up on a touch screen.
It looks more about this long time known and not fixed Bootstrap bug:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16028

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and found a solution. Hope this helps some one else looking for an answer. Add the following code to your website:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); // close on body click 
// iOS doesnt recognise 'body' click so using :not 
$(':not(#anything)').on('click', function (e) { 
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () { 
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) { 
            $(this).popover('hide'); 
        } 
    });
});
```

All credits to **stelco** at this [URL](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16028)